# Python Library (rembg) NOT working with www-data user

Tags: permissions, python, nginx, laravel

I'm using `rembg` library in `Python` and using it with my `Larvel` project, I've tried multiple ways to execute Python file from my PHP application, like `symfony/process`, `shell_exec`, `artisan` But this file is not working.

File work fine with simple Python usage, like `print("testing")`, but if i tried to use any library like `rembg` in my `Python File`, it gives error. After debugging for several hours, I've ended up with this error that PHP files are using `www-data` user instead of my user. And `www-data` is not permitted to Python modules.

[image]

```
USER_BASE: '/var/www/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/var/www/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
```

Please any help. I'm new to Python
Thanks

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: i'm using 20.04 LTS